# How can I set the value of a Html.DropDownList in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, dropdownlistfor

I am working on an edit form and I am unable to set the value shown in an `Html.DropDownList` based on the model value.

This is what I have so far:

```
@Html.DropDownList("OrgId", 
                   (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.orgList, 
                   Model.ShortName, 
                   new { @class = "form-select", @style="width:120px"})
```

When the form loads it does have the correct `ShortName` corresponding to the model, but when the form is submitted the index associated with the `ShortName` is 0 instead of the `Id`. It is just adding the `ShortName` at the top of the list and not setting it to the correct index in the list.

In the controller `ViewBag.orgList` is being set thus:

```
ViewBag.orgList = new SelectList(_context.Organizations
                                         .Where(x => x.Id != 0)
                                         .OrderBy(p => p.ShortName), 
                                 "Id", "ShortName");
```

Maybe I should be using `DropDownListFor` but I am new to ASP.NET Core MVC and don't know which is the best option.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Why don't you use `<select>` tag in html? Just refer to this [Docs](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/net-core-5-dropdownlist/).

Comment: @XinranShen.  I think you missed the point of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution although it feels a bit hacky:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ShortName", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.orgList, Model.ShortName, new { @class = "form-select", @id="ShortName"})
```

This then allows you to pass a string ShortName to a controller Action method.  Works!!